# How many square numbers mod $2^n$

Tags: number-theory

How many square numbers are there$\bmod 2^n$?

I'm looking for an expression in terms of $n$. Tried the first few cases but spotted nothing.

Comment: Are you asking how many squares are less than $2^{n}$ or how many solutions there are to the equation $x^{2}\equiv {k \mod 2^{n}}$?

Comment: You might do better looking at odd squares and even squares separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$m=p_1^{k_1}\cdotp_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$$

$$m^2=p_1^{2k_1}\cdotp_2^{2k_2}\cdots p_r^{2k_r}$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose that $x = y^2$ is an odd square modulo $2^n$.  Then $2^{2k}x$ is also a square for any (positive) integer $k$, and $2^{2k - 1}x$ *is not* a square.